# How to write Regex to extract first few characters from specific word without or without ending delimiters?

Tags: regex, splunk

I have the following string and would like to extract the first few characters until the end of the word or until "Response"

```
<ns2:GetJobStatus
<ns10:JobIDResponse
<ns2:JobStatusResponse
<ns3:GetJobId
```

I would like the regular expression such that I could extract either GetJobStatus and GetJobID from all the above lines. I would like to drop "Response" from the result, such that I would get 2 of each in the above example. This is in splunk so I can't use awk or sed or any other unix /linux commands.

Here's what I have done so far

```
<ns\d+:(?P<ws_name>.+?)(?:Response)
```

with the above I am able to extract only where there is "Response"

Comment: Expected output please.

Comment: @ClaesWikner It's right there among the lines.

Comment: Is your input XML or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're off to a good start. What you need to find after your `ws_name` group is either the word `Response` ***or*** a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Therefore, all you need to do is add `|\b` in your non-capturing group:

```
<ns\d+:(?P<ws_name>.+?)(?:Response|\b)
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WEtFLk/1).

**References:**

[Alternation in Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I was so close and still couldn't figure out. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

With lookbehind and lookahead, you should be able to get the result you want with the pattern

```
(?<=:)(\w+?)(?=Response|\b|$)
```

You would be interested in the capture group `(\w+?)` because it'll come after the ":" character and be before the word "Response".  The "\b|$" sets a word boundary or end of line.

Tested at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TEkQFH/2)

Comment: (\w+?) worked but not the (?<=:). But thanks for your response..appreciate it.

Comment: I guess Regex101 is lying with the results it gave then.

Comment: @Shar1er80 I never used Splunk, so I don't really know. Perhaps it doesn't support Lookbehinds? BTW, `|$` is redundant here.